# how to select value from drop down in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am writing code to automate a form page having drop down but stuck on one part.

I was able to click on drop down list and list is opened but unable to select value from it , can find a way to do it by `visibletext` ,`by index,by value.`

stuck after this part :-

```
WebElement dropdown1 = (driver.findElement(By.id("select2-SelectedPatientId-container")));  
dropdown1.click();
```

Comment: Can you share HTML code ?

Comment: Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedDoctorId")));  
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Huma Doctor (Primary)");  
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("appointmentmodelpopup")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn-submit-secretaryAppointment")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    WebElement dropdown1 = (driver.findElement(By.id("select2-SelectedPatientId-container")));  
    dropdown1.click();

Comment: AS i mentioned i am able to open drop down by this code     WebElement dropdown1 = (driver.findElement(By.id("select2-SelectedPatientId-container")));  
dropdown1.click();     but after that i am stuck

Comment: As I mentioned before I need to see your HTML first, Select and option is only valid if you see Select in HTML as well

Comment: i want to select this value from HTML code <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-SelectedPatientId-container" title="tesr test">tesr test</span>

Comment: You can not use above method , I mean Select in your code

Comment: Any other method?

Comment: Did you try directly clicking on the option when the options are getting displayed ?

Comment: you mean on the drop down list then selecting value

Comment: You can't use Select class to select drop-down. As you are able to click on element dropdown1 then write an xPath for drop-down value(Let's say value1) and click on element value1.